# Measuring PSR of a current reference chip

Tags: noise, current-measurement, spectrum-analyzer, reference, vna

**Some Background:**

*I'm designing a test board to characterize noise and PSR of a multiple voltages(1V) and currents(1uA) reference IC. The chip has a single voltage source.  I use ultra low noise MUX and deMUX to switch between various voltage/current signals As, I plan to have one Spectrum Analyzer SA44B and one VNA Bode100 only. I also have ultra low noise buffers (MAX4238) before the inputs to the SA and VNA. I'm interested in measuring in the 10Hz to 100KHz range only. 
The simulated  specs for the voltage reference: PSR 100dB and Noise: 10 uVrms.
The simulated  specs for the current reference: PSR 65dB and Noise: 85 uVrms.*

**Now, my question:**

1. When measuring noise for current reference signal, can the spectrum analyzer directly take a current signal? (or) Should I convert to voltage with a shunt resistor? I don't like the latter because, the resistor would introduce noise of around 20mVrms in the system. (Voltage noise calculated for room temperature and 100KHz BW and 1Mohm)
2. Similar case for VNA receiver, can it take a current signal? As I dont want to introduce any noise in such a critical measurement.

Thank you :)
--San

Answer (score 0):

There is a book called Power Integrity by Steven Sandler that goes into detail on how to do this. He uses the BODE100 VNA that you mentioned.